# Запуск потока 32бит из 64бит

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность, x86-64

В приложении x64 невозможно пользоваться инструментом, так как для него присутствуют только 32 битные внешние компоненты (sapi5). Создавать отдельный процесс или поднимать сервер не хочется.

В [этой](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/winapi/4870295.hot) теме говорится, что вроде бы можно:

> В двух словах: 64->64 ok, 64->32 ok,
> 32->32 ok, 32->64 fail

1. Возможно ли?
2. Есть ли какие нибудь проблемы с этим(с указателями там)?
3. Есть ли проблемы совместимости(будет ли работать на всех 64 бит процессорах)?
4. Работаю с std::thread(так же есть boost), есть ли там такая возможность?
5. Какое лучшее решение?

Comment: Мне кажется, что в рамках 32-битного процесса это сделать нельзя. Думаю, что единственное решение - отдельный 64-битный процесс (а мы его запустить из 32-битного можем завсегда).

Comment: Пока запускаю отдельный .exe через WINAPI CreateProcess(). Работает как надо.

Правильно ли понимаю, что выполнить код(x32), в этом же процессе(x64) невозможно?

Comment: http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=319